# Replace EOL in stream

Tags: c#, performance, stream

I need to replace the windows EOL "\r\n" with just "\n", and I want to this in the fastest way possible, as the software will have a lot of files to upload, many of them with a few thousands lines.  My current approach is:

```
UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
using (MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (TextReader stream = new StreamReader(fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line = await stream.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            line += "\n";
            await newStream.WriteAsync(uniEncoding.GetBytes(line), 0, line.Length);
        }
    }

    client.UploadFile(newStream, remote, true);
}
```

Another approach I was considering was to wrap the Stream I get from the file, and just not return the `\n` when read. I think this would consume less memory, but I am not sure if this would cause more problems as I have never really worked with streams.

Any feedback on my current approach / alternatives would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested that this works? It looks like the call to `WriteAsync` is incorrect - it should be the number of `byte`s to write, not the number of `char`s.

Comment: I'm curious about your requirement, you indicate you want to replace "\r\n" with "\n", but would it be sufficient to simply strip all "\r" characters? Is it valid to have a "\r" character *not* followed by a "\n"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Performance**

- The non-Async methods are much faster in case of ReadLine/Write. If you need to run the code in background, use `await Task.Run(/* put the whole code here */);`

**Encoding**

- You can use the static property `Encoding.Unicode`. (It is the same as creating a `UnicodeEncoding` instance without constructor arguments)
- Add the Encoding to the stream reader: `new StreamReader(fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.Unicode)`. Otherwise, if the input file is not unicode encoded, the output becomes a bunch of trash.